# Relative Risk calculation with continuous variable

Tags: r

I have to calculate Risk Ratio with 95% CI for a dichotomous outcome and continuous independent variable. How can I manage it? I've tried with riskCommunicator but obtained an error that I'm unable to solve.
I've also checked the used variables.

```
install.packages("printr")
library(riskCommunicator)
library(tidyverse)
library(printer)

db$Reparto_OUT<-as.factor(db$Reparto_OUT)

cvdd.formula <- db$Reparto_OUT ~ db$t0_FIO1


binary.res.alt2 <- gComp(data = db, 
                         formula = cvdd.formula, 
                         outcome.type = "binary", 
                         R = 200, 
                         Y = NULL, 
                         X = NULL, 
                         Z = NULL, 
                         subgroup = NULL, 
                         offset = NULL, 
                         rate.multiplier = 1, 
                         clusterID = NULL, 
                         parallel = "no", 
                         ncpus = 1)
```

the error I obtained:

```
Error in ifelse(is.numeric(data[[X]]), mean(data[[X]]), stop("X must be a factor or numeric variable")) : 
  X must be a factor or numeric variable
```

my data:

```
db$Reparto_OUT 
  [1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 [49] 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
 [97] 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1
[145] 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
[193] 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
[241] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
[289] 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
[337] 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1

db$t0_FIO1
  [1] 100  21  21  21  21 100  21  21  21  21  21 100 100 100 100  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  21
 [25]  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  21 100  21  21 100 100  21  21  21 100  21  21  21  21  21  21
 [49]  21  21  21  21 100  21  21  60  21  21  40  21  21 100  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  21 100  21
 [73]  21  21  21  21 100  21  21  21  21  21 100  40  21  21 100  40  21 100  21  21 100  21 100  21
 [97] 100  21  21 100  21  21  40  21  21  40  21  40 100  21  21  21 100  40 100  21  40 100 100  21
[121]  40 100  60  21 100  21 100 100  21 100  60  21  21  40  60  40 100 100 100  40 100  21  21 100
[145] 100 100 100 100  21  21  50  21  21  21  21  21  21  60  80  21  21  21  21 100 100 100 100 100
[169]  21  21  21  21  21  21 100  21 100  21  21  80 100 100 100 100 100  50  21 100 100  21  21  21
[193]  21  21  21  21  21 100  21  21  21  NA  21  21 100 100  70  24  21  60  21  40 100 100  80  28
[217] 100 100  21  21  50  21 100 100 100  31  21  21  21  21  21  21 100  24  21  21  21 100  21  21
[241]  50  21 100 100 100  21 100 100  50  21 100 100  40 100  50  21 100  21  21  21 100  31  21  40
[265]  21  80 100  50  21 100 100 100  40  21  40  60  21  21  21  21  21 100  21  85  21 100 100  60
[289]  21 100 100 100 100 100  21  50  40  50  50  21  40  60  21  50  40  21  21  21 100  21 100 100
[313]  50  21 100  21  21 100  21 100  21  21 100  21  21  21  21  21  21  21 100  21  60  21  21  21
[337]  21 100  21  21  35  21  21  21  70 100 100  80 100  80  21  21  28  21  40  21  60  21  40  21
[361]  21  21  21  21  21  21  80  21  80  50  21  21  21  21  90  80 100  21  21 100 100  21  35 100

> is.numeric(db$t0_FIO1 ) 
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(db$Reparto_OUT ) 
[1] FALSE
> is.factor(db$Reparto_OUT ) 
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: My guess is you don't need to include subsetting the data.frame when building your formula. Try `cvdd.formula <- Reparto_OUT ~ t0_FIO1` instead. You do provide the data source when calling `gComp`.